# Import bol.com transactions

Tags: affiliate

I have a problem where I want to import bol.com (an affiliate network) transactions into my own PHP website. However, the transaction report they provide in their website login area is in Flash so I cannot read it through CURL etc.
They do not provide any API either. Is there anyone out there who could suggest how I could do that? I am stuck on it and really need help.

Comment: any help guys.. bumpty bump bump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, bol.com are writing their own API currently which should be out soon.